# Different ways of calling a function in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to figure out a slight difference here. Say I have a button, which calls a function when clicked. There are two different ways I have done it, one wrong and another right.

*ApproachA:*

```
<Input onChange = {function()}/>
```

*ApproachB:*

```
<Input onChange = {function}/>
```

When using AppeoachA, I am unable to call the function, react throws an error (Too many re-renders. React limits the amount of renders to prevent an infinite loop). However, when I make it an arrow function ( seen in ApproachA.1), I am able to call the function but this approach does not work when the function is working with data input.

*Approach A.1*

```
<Input onChange = {()=> function() }/>
```

When using ApproachB, I do not get an error and the input changes as expected.

Why is this the case? Can someone explain the difference to me? Also, what is the effect of passing an argument in either approach? Does one become more suitable than the other?

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) first; note the difference between when you are using JSX and when you are not. If you have specific questions after reading that, we can help.

Answer (score 1):

`function()` isn't a function, it is the return value of that function. So while internally, your Input onChange is expecting a function to pass around, calling function() invokes the function and passes that return value instead (which likely causes issues when e.g. a string or number is treated like a function).

Similarly, `() => function()` is itself a function, which thus doesn't cause these data type issues.